# Specific cell linked to Word causes Excel hangs

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2010

I have named over 200 specific cells in excel and have pasted them as link in a Word document for easy updating the Word file each time the Excel file is updated.

However, both Word and Excel often hang or stop working if those two files are open together. The size of Excel and Word files are 800KB and 1000KB.

Please advise how to avoid the issue of Excel and Word hanging.

Comment: Are these files stored on a network drive? Are there a lot of calculations in the Excel file? Do the programs recover after a period or do you have to force close them?

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click File then scroll down to Options.
2. Uncheck the checkbox "Enable Live Preview" under user interface options.

Comment: many thanks. Is there a way to disable Live Preview in a particular word document